# Datastax Driver for cassandra and solr integration

Tags: jdbc, solr, cassandra, datastax

I'm trying to integrate Solr-6.6.0 and Cassandra-3.10. I tried using JDBC of cassandra and I got to know that Cassandra JDBC does not support to the latest versions. Then, I came across Datastax Driver. So, right now I'm using Datastax cassandra-driver-core-3.1.4 as my java jar file.

solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="solr.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="config">sample-data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

I added the above lines.

sample-data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.datastax.driver.core.Connection" url="jdbc:cassandra://127.0.0.1:9042/demo" autoCommit="true"/>
<document name="content">
    <entity name="test" query="SELECT id,org,name,dep,place,sal from tutor" autoCommit="true">
        <field column="id" name="id" />
        <field column="org" name="org" />
        <field column="name" name="name" />
        <field column="dep" name="dep" />
        <field column="place" name="place" />
        <field column="sal" name="sal" />
    </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

where tutor is my table and demo is my keyspace.

manageschema.xml

```
<field name="org" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="dep" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="place" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="sal" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

Added the above lines to manage schema

Jar files added to lib folder of my core are

- cassandra-driver-core-3.1.4.jar
- cassandra-driver-extras-3.1.4.jar
- cassandra-driver-mapping-3.1.4.jar

Now, when I run solr dih files, core does not give any requests as well it does not show any error messages. I'm throughly out of my mind.

[image]

[image]

Can we use the specified jar files to connect cassandra and solr? If so, where I'm wrong? Or else if we need to use the integrated one are we supposed to use only DSE search?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running community version of Cassandra and Solr or DSE product?

Comment: No, not the DSE product. Individual apache versions, I'm running.